# Writing a native language compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, executable, native

I've to implement my custom native-compiled Windows programming language. Is there an easier way then translating it to ASM, or translating it to C/C++ and then use a C/C++ compiler? Is there any SDK or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ANTLR](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/99-06-050) library

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh yeaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a better link to [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) ?

There is also a [tutorial](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/docs/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/antlr/antlr.html)

And at least one [book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference)

Comment: This belong in the comment under my answer, genius.

Comment: I don't really understand, the ANTLR is translating my own language to another?

Comment: Yes it handles all the details of parsing your language and then by generating C/python etc it also saves you dealing with the details of assembler on your platform. It's a replacemnet for YACC/Lex etc.

Answer (score 0):

[LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) can run under Visual Studio

Comment: this is one is not bad either, though pales in comparison to my answer!!

Comment: @Andrei, i wasn't going to mention ANTLR since you did it, but LLVM is a good alternative.